# Matching multiline comments in regex

Tags: regular-expressions, comment

I'm writing a major mode for a language that uses `(* ... *)` as comments.

I'm trying to match multi-line comments. e.g.

```
(*
foo
bar
*)
```

I was initially doing `"(\\*.*\\*)"`, however, `.` doesn't match newline.

I then tried what the wiki on [multi-line regex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultilineRegexp) said: `"(\\*[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*\\*)"`. However, this leads to matching that I wasn't expecting. For instance, if I have the following:

```
(* comment 1*)
code block 1

(* comment 2*)
code block 2

(* comment 3*)
code block 3
```

It highlights everything from `comment 1` to `comment 3` as a big comment, including `code block 1` and `code block 2`.

How can I get it to match `(*` to the first closing `*)` rather than the last one?

Comment: `.` matches any character but a newline, you have to to use `(.|\n)`. This however is inefficient when there are several newlines. Better match multiple lines with `(.*\n?)*` instead. The newline is optional so that the expression can end in the middle of a line.

Comment: I think `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]` is better than `(.*\n?)*`, which is so slow it crashes emacs on my computer. However, my problem isn't matching newline, but matching `(*` with the first `*)`. As I explain in the question, it matches the last `*)`, which is not good. I have tried matching everything but `(*` in the blocks, but it doesn't seem to match things character by character, rather, it matches the whole thing.

Comment: Typically, when you are matching comment using regexp:s, you are using the wrong tool. Instead, make sure your major mode set up the syntax table correctly and use functions like `syntax-ppss` to check if you are in a comment, `forward-comment` to move over comments etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to change the wildcard match to a non-greedy version (`+?`,`??`,`*?`).  Ref: [Emacs Manual: Regexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html)

In this case:

```
(\\*[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*?\\*)
```

That tells it to find the shortest full match, rather than the longest.

Comment: Note that `"(\\*[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*?\\*)toto"` will still match the whole `(*foo*)titi(*bar*)toto`, so in some cases the non-greedy solution is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was not aware of the `*?` to match as little as possible.

Answer (score 3):

See Jonathan's answer for the easy solution.  The hard solution would look something like:

```
(\*\(?:[^*]\|\*+[^)*]\)*\*+)
```

Comment: Just have to double up the ``\`` to match his request (I'm assuming for use in elisp not just as a re-search).

Comment: That goes along with adding double quotes around it, yes.

Comment: `(\\*\\(?:[^*]\\|\\*+[^)*]\\)*\\*+)` works too. I was also thinking of doing it this way (i.e. matching `(*` but not matching any `(* ... *)` in between), but it seemed awkward, like something the regexp should handle instead. `*?` does the job.

Comment: Don't think [^*]\|\*+[^)*] makes sense here. Both parts are not sufficient, resp. not required. Would need a look-ahead assertion WRT "*" followed by a ")".